# Import CSV file using MEAN stack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I want to import CSV file using MEAN stack. I would want the data in the CSV file as JSON to do further operation on them. I am not sure on how to do it. Any advice or guidance on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `$http` to get the file and then parse it to array. Not hard to find parsing code for a csv to json

Comment: Note that assumes you mean import client side....you weren't specific about where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep in mind that you should never process the file in front-end. Always do it in back-end.

In your case, [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) would we a good library to upload the CSV file from AngularJS to ExpressJS.

In your ExpressJS app, import `multer` to use as middleware like so

```
var multer = require("multer");

app.post("/api/file-upload",
          multer({
                 "dest": <your_folder_destination>
          }).single("file"),
          function(request, response)
{
    // processing goes here
});
```

On your AngularJS side, your HTTP request, you can send the file as `FormData` like so:

```
this.fileUpload = function (file) {
     var formData = new FormData();
     formData.append("file", file);
     return $http({
         "method": "POST",
         "url": "/api/file-upload",
         "data": formData,
         "transformRequest": angular.identity,
         "headers": {
            "Content-Type": undefined
         }
     });
};
```

Multer's Documentation and AngularJS multi-part HTTP Request tutorials would be a good start